# How to sort databound control when datasource caching is on

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

The SqlDataSource.Selected event does not fire when SqlDataSource caching is enabled and the server loads data from cache.

I was using the selected method and SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs to sort my data, but it doesnt fire sometimes.

Anyone have any ideas on an alternate way to sort when data comes from cache?

```
Protected Sub sdsSupplies_Selecting(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles sdsSupplies.Selecting

        e.Arguments.SortExpression = "SortedColumnID ASC"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you intercept the DataBinding event?

Comment: The SqlDataSource DataBinding event does not fire either. I have a Repeater control bound to it, its event does fire but I don't think you can sort there. I am thinking the solution might be to sort SQL side or to not allow caching.

Comment: Currently I'm not at the computer. But does the SqlDataSource allow for select parameters? Setting the sorting as parameter might enforce a new query.

Comment: I believe it does allow, however you are essentially telling it not to use cache by changing the parameter signature. Might as well turn off caching. In my case, it was reverting to the original native row sequence after the 2nd or 3rd postback. My sort order is static, I am just letting IIS sort rather than SQL.